# Probability in Statistics

Tags: probability

An Olympic archer is able to hit the bull's-eye 80% of the time. Assume each shot is independent of the others. If she shoots 10 arrows, what's the probability that she hits the bull's-eye more often then she misses?

Comment: Do you know to compute probabilities using the binomial distribution?

Comment: Yes I know how to use the formulas for binomial distribution

Answer (score 1):

If she hits the bullseye more often than she misses, then she would've hit the bullseye more than $5$ times. You can compute each case separately (once for each of $6$, $7$, $8$, $9$, and $10$ times she hits the bullseye) then add them. Since you know how to use the binomial distribution formulas, you can do that. I'll do the first one for you:

Hitting the bullseye $6$ times means missing it $4$ times:
$$P(6 \text{ hits})={10\choose 6}\times 0.8^{6}\times0.2^4=0.088$$
Can you continue with the other $4$ cases?